# Solution to mixed ODE and Integral Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let $X = [a, b]^2$, and consider the unknown function $f:X\times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. Also, let $A:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a known function with positive entries. Assume $f$ satisfies the differential equation

\begin{equation*}
\partial_tf(x, y, t) + A(x, y)f(x, y, t) - \int_{a}^{b}A(y, z)f(y, z, t)dz = 0.
\end{equation*}

I've not run into something like this before, so I'm unsure if there are particular methods for finding $f$ in exact form, or if I'm going to ultimately have to reduce it to a computational problem. Any references would be welcome.

Comment: The integral is equal to a constant, meaning the equation is a first order linear ODE.

Comment: The integral is still a function of $y$ and $t$.

Comment: you are correct

Comment: I have a similar ode to solve, did you figure it out?